# Nuxeo DAM system: Get document by file:content/data

Tags: sql, nuxeo, dam

I would like to execute an (NXQL) query which would return to me the document based on the file:content/data field. 
I have tried several different ways of writing the query down but nothing seems to be working for me.

Could you please tell me is it (and how) possible to retrieve a document via REST API or .NET Client based on the download link of the asset(file:content/data)?

I look forward to hearing from you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I believe why querying based on **file:content/data** field is not working is because digest value is actually stored instead of link in a data field

[image]

Alternative Solution would be querying based on **file:content/name**. If you have a LINK like

```
http://host:port/nuxeo/nxfile/default/cfb12863-3ac2-4778-8b4b-06a275a7943b/report:file/2017-Gartner-MQ-CSP.jpg?changeToken=1-0"
```

Here '2017-Gartner-MQ-CSP.jpg' is the name of a file

So NXQL Query would be->

```
SELECT * FROM Document WHERE report:file/name = '2017-Gartner-MQ-CSP.jpg'
```

And REST API would be->

```
http://host:port/nuxeo/api/v1/search/lang/NXQL/execute?query=SELECT * FROM Document WHERE report:file/name = '2017-Gartner-MQ-CSP.jpg'&properties=*
```